# How to put contacts on the android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, contacts, android-contacts

I'm trying to write my first android app. It deals with contacts and contact groups. In order to test on the emulator, I'm trying to add contacts with groups to the emulator. If I try to add them manually, it goes through the whole contact dialog, I click **done** and it goes away but doesn't actually save the contact.

I tried syncing the phone to a test gmail account, but after poking around, I see that doesn't work either because of an issue with needing a unique IMEI number.

So I found a thread which said create the contacts in gmail.com, then export them to a vcf file and use adb to push them to the emulator and then import them into `Contacts`. I tried this, the file copied over okay, and I ran the import, which showed a progress bar and the contact names being imported. It looked like it worked, but then it goes back to `Contacts` and did not actually save them into the database.

So, is there ANY way to add contacts with groups into the emulator? Or do I need to build the apk and test it actually on my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you've a virtual sdcard in your emulator (= created a device with an virtual sdcard). Your error might be because your emulator cannot store the data because of a missing sdcard.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Yes, I created the device with an sd card of 128MB. I confirmed just now in the AVD Manager; the details of that specific device does show the SD card @ 128MB, so I'm assuming it should be recognizing it.

Comment: so, just to be sure, you simply cannot add any contacts in your emulator - even entering them manually through "add contacts"? if so, try to create a new virtual device with nothing but bare android, and try again. if this is already not working, something is seriously wrong.

Comment: Yes, looks like that was it. I was completely unable to a contact any which way - in my `Google API` avd. In my `Android SDK` one I was able to. So I recreated the Google one, and now it works. Whatev. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Related to @eidylon's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615853/android-2-x-vs-google-apis-for-android-avd-setup

Answer (score 2):

There is another thing that might hide your contact. I have to change display option to show all contact.